# Calculating unique combination

Tags: java, math

I have done bit of research before asking this question but did not get the appropriate answer. I have to calculate unique possible combination from a set of 2 categories. Each categories has some values. For example in Category 1 there are 3 values, in category 2 there are 4 values.

Example:

```
Category1     Category2
  A             D
  B             E
                F
```

The unique combination I am looking for is (A, AD, AE, AF, B, BD, BE, BF, D, E, F). These are 11 combination. What I need is a formula which will calculate this.

Comment: `I have done bit of research ..` Err, you mean `search`?

Comment: Yes I meant not re-eventing the wheel. :)

Comment: You'll be more likely to pass the class if you do the homework yourself...

Comment: Think about '' as possible solution, shouldn't this be included?

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
for (String a: cat1){
  for (String b: cat2){
     s.add(a + b)    
  }
}
s.addAll(cat1);
s.addAll(cat2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I read the question as wanting to calculate the number of potential combinations, not wanting to actually determine what those combinations are. In that case:

Let A equal the number of options in category one and B equal the number of options in category two.

Then result = (A * B) + A + B.

Comment: What if we have more than two categories?

Comment: @user1794058 Multiply the number of elements they each have together, then add the number of elements in each group to the result of that.

Answer (score 1):

For a set containing *n* elements, you have *n* possible elements to choose from, so in your example you have 2*3 = 6 combinations. As I see, you want to include combinations where only an element from one of the categories is chosen. That gives 2*3 + 2 + 3 = 11 (2*3 combinations with one element per category, 2 combinations with only elements from cat1, and 3 combinations with only elements from cat2).

Let n1 be the number of elements in cat1 and n2 the number in cat2, then your formula would be n1*n2+n1+n2. If you want to include the combination containing no elements at all, add 1.

Answer (score 0):

Unique combination = Category1 union Category2 union (Category1 x Category2)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over both the categories.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String first : new String[] {"A", "B", ""}) {
        for (String second : new String[] {"", "D", "E", "F"}) {
            String combination = first + second;
            if (combination.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(combination);
        }
    }
}
```